# How using isin inside lambda

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
Open_Time_s=['2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00', np.nan, np.nan]
intersect=[np.nan,np.nan,'intersect_2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','intersect_2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00']
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Open Time':Open_Time_s,'intersect':intersect})
df['LEVEL']=np.nan
```

looking for matches on all lines 'Open Time' values intersect.
You need to write the index values to the column 'LEVEL'

Using code : `df['LEVEL']=df['intersect'].loc[df['intersect'].isna()==0].apply(lambda x: df[df['Open Time'].isin(x.replace(r'intersect_', ''))].index)`

return error : only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str].
What is the possible alternative .isin ?

please tell me how to write similar code using lambda function:`df[df['Open Time'].isin(df['intersect'].str.replace(r'intersect_', ''))].index.tolist()`

need result :

```
         Open Time                        intersect                LEVEL
0  2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00                                  NaN    NaN
1  2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00                                  NaN    NaN
2                       None  intersect_2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00    0
3                       None  intersect_2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00    1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you mean by "looking for matches on all lines 'Open Time' values intersect. You need to write the index values to the column 'LEVEL'"  What times do you want to intersect with 'Open_Time'?  What index do you want posted to df['Level'} column?  Please provide a sample of your expected output, given a small sample of the input.

Comment: I wrote , search for values 'intersect' in a field 'Open Time'. you can see it in the code below. Also wrote that I want to get the result in the 'level' index value field, the found values of the 'intersect' field in  field 'Open Time'. As can be seen from the data, the values of the 'intersect ' field require processing in order for matches to be found.

Comment: for example, the correct result can be obtained like this : df[df['Open Time'].isin(df['intersect'].str.replace(r'intersect_', ''))].index.tolist(). I need to get the value of the found index in the field 'LEVEL'USING LAMBDA.

Comment: Please edit your original question and show what you expect the final data will look like.  I am not following your explanation.

Comment: `'Open Time':intersect` should be `'Open Time':Open_Time_s`?

Comment: you are right it should be

Comment: I just noticed the inaccuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
Open_Time_s=['2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00', np.nan, np.nan]
intersect=[np.nan,np.nan,'intersect_2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','intersect_2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00']    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Open Time':Open_Time_s,'intersect':intersect})
```

Doing:

```
df[['intersect', 'intersect_time']] = df['intersect'].str.split('_', expand=True)

df['LEVEL'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df['Open Time'].eq(x['intersect_time'])].index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                   Open Time  intersect             intersect_time LEVEL
0  2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00        NaN                        NaN    []
1  2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00        NaN                        NaN    []
2                        NaN  intersect  2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00   [0]
3                        NaN  intersect  2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00   [1]
```